# Load custom language for fmtcount?

Tags: languages, fmtcount

I have written a file [`fc-swedish.def`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/issues/47) to make [`fmtcount`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) support Swedish numbers. Is there some way for me to load that file locally without copying the entire package to my working directory?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `load that file locally without copying the entire package to my working directory`? From `fmtcount.sty` it just looks for `fc-lang.def` and it is input if found, so it is enough to have `fx-swedish.def` in the current directory.

Comment: @daleif Good point. If I copy `fmtcount.sty` into the current directory, then I can edit its list of languages to include Swedish which allows to just `\usepackage[swedish]{fmtcount}` in the preamble. But I can’t figure out how to do it without editing the `.sty` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be fairly simple once `babel` was included.

```
\documentclass[swedish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\FCloadlang{swedish}
\begin{document}
  \Ordinalstringnum{12}
\end{document}
```

As a confusing sidenote, it also worked without `babel` as long as some other language than Swedish was supplied as a class option:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\FCloadlang{swedish}
\begin{document}
  \Ordinalstringnum{12}
\end{document}
```