# \eappto and \aa doesn't work with pdflatex without fontenc

Tags: pdftex, etoolbox, diacritical-mark

I'm trying to use `\aa` in an `\eappto` command. The minimal code  below works just fine in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but fails with pdfLaTeX unless I include the `fontenc` package. This confuses me as `\aa` works perfectly outside of the `\eappto` command also without the `fontenc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zz}{%
  \def\@tmp{}%
  \eappto\@tmp{\aa}%
  \@tmp%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \aa tta% works just fine
  \zz% only works with `fontenc`
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should always use T1 enoding for Swedish in pdflatex, or hyphenation will be wrong, also you can not in general apply `\edef` to latex constructs. That said utf-8 characters are `\protected` so safe in an `\edef` so if you really want this, simply use `å` rather than `\aa`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zz}{%
  \def\@tmp{}%
  \eappto\@tmp{å}%
  \@tmp%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \aa tta % works just fine
  \zz tta    % only works with `fontenc`
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have an old latex you can use the standard latex `\protected@edef` rather than rely on unsupported edef use.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zz}{%
  \def\@tmp{}%
  \protected@edef\@tmp{\@tmp å}%
  \@tmp%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \aa tta % works just fine
  \zz tta    % only works with `fontenc`
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: you must have an old latex release, what version do you have?

Comment: pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)

Comment: @FredrikP I added a version for that

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `\aa` is

```
\r a
```

The definition of `\r` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is

```
\TU-cmd \r \TU\r
```

and we can see that the definition of `\TU\r` (which is a strange command with a backslash in its name) is

```
#1->\@text@composite \TU\r #1\@empty \@text@composite {\add@unicode@accent {"030A}{#1}}.
```

and `\r a` turns out to expand to the single Unicode character `å`.

With the default OT1 encoding in pdflatex, the `\r` command becomes a complicated construction aimed to add the ring accent above the `a`, which doesn't survive the `\edef` used by `\eappto`.

On the other hand, with T1 the situation is similar to the previous one, because T1 encoded fonts have a precomposed `å` character.

However, I'd not recommend using such encoding dependent commands in `\edef` under any circumstance.

Comment: Is there any alternative? I need to append the word "åtta" to `\@tmp`

Comment: @FredrikP Is there any reason for using `\eappto` instead of `\appto`? But perhaps there are even better methods. Please try and be clearer about your real problem.

Comment: In the less minimal code (a [Swedish addition to `fmtcount`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674596/load-custom-language-for-fmtcount), the word "åtta" is actually stored in a command taking an argument. Something like `\newcommand*\@unitstring[1]{\ifcase#1 noll \or {\aa}tta \fi}`. And I use `\eappto` to append that command.

Comment: @FredrikP That's too cryptic, sorry.

Comment: New attempt before going to bed :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675060/cannot-use-aa-in-eappto

Comment: @FredrikP you can use `åtta` why do you need `\aa` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It won't compile for me with pdfLaTeX if I use write "åtta".