# Can't capitalize Swedish letters (å, ä, ö) with pdfTeX

Tags: pdftex, capitalization, fmtcount, diacritical-mark

I'm working on a Swedish language file to [`fmtcount`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/) and, to support some of `fmtcount`'s commands (e.g. `\Numberstring` and `NUMBERstring`), I need to make strings containing the Swedish characters `å`, `ä` and `ö` uppercase. This seems unproblematic with `XeTeX` and `LuaTeX`, but not so much in `pdfTeX`.

### The macro level

A full version of what I want to do that involves as little of my LaTeX fumbling as possible would be the example below. As my own language file is based on the German language file ([`fc-german.def`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/blob/master/trunk/fc-german.def)), I here make a minimal change to that file to highlight the problem, which leads to the compilation with `pdfTeX` simply not finishing. Without my change the document reads "Acht" and with my change I had hoped that it would read "Åtta".

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\FCloadlang{german}
\makeatletter
% Redefine code from fc-german.def
\renewcommand*\@@unitstringgerman[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    null%
    \or ein%
    \or zwei%
    \or drei%
    \or vier%
    \or f\"unf%
    \or sechs%
    \or sieben%
    \or åtta% Changed from "acht" to "åtta"
    \or neun%
  \fi
}%
\global\let\@@unitstringgerman\@@unitstringgerman
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{mycounter}
  \setcounter{mycounter}{8} \themycounter\ \Numberstring{mycounter}\\
\end{document}
```

- If I uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the compilation still does not finish.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta`, then the compilation crashes.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta` **and** uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the compilation again does not finish.

### My fumbling attempt to approach the micro level

I **think** that this example has the same problem as the macro level one. It at least sure behaves the same way. (It is probably very related to [my last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675057/eappto-and-aa-doesnt-work-with-pdflatex-without-fontenc).)

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@@unitstringgerman[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    null%
    \or ein%
    \or zwei%
    \or drei%
    \or vier%
    \or f\"unf%
    \or sechs%
    \or sieben%
    \or åtta% Changed from "acht" to "åtta"
    \or neun%
  \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\zz}{% Supposed to make the first letter of `\@@unitstringgerman{8}` (i.e. "åtta") uppercase
  \def\one{}%
  \def\two{}%
  \eappto\two{\@@unitstringgerman{8}}%
  \edef\one{\noexpand\MakeUppercase\expandonce\two}%
  \one%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \zz
\end{document}
```

- If I uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the compilation still does not finish.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta`, then the compilation crashes.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta` **and** uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the compilation again does not finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titlecasing is best left to the proper command. With a reasonably up-to-date LaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@@unitstringgerman[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    null%
    \or ein%
    \or zwei%
    \or drei%
    \or vier%
    \or f\"unf%
    \or sechs%
    \or sieben%
    \or åtta% Changed from "acht" to "åtta"
    \or neun%
  \fi
}%
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
  \MakeTitlecase{\@@unitstringgerman{8}}
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

(The 'classical' approach of grabbing only one token using `\MakeUppercase` will fail with 8-bit engines and non-ASCII input, quite apart from the small number of cases where uppercasing and titlecasing are different.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of `\MakeTitlecase`. Surprisingly, it behaves as titlecasing is done in Swedish, i.e. it just uppercases the very first letter. I would have thought that it would take a (completely arbitrary) title such as "Electronic control of the protonation rates of Fe-Fe bonds" and turn it into "Electronic Control of the Protonation Rates of Fe-Fe Bonds". Is there anywhere I could read about it?

Comment: It's in LaTeX News, or `usrguide`; 'titlecase' is the Unicode term for changing the first 'character' only of a string: applying it to every word would be a higher-level function

Answer (score 0):

This answer incorporates mostly the insight from [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675344/71332) into the examples in the original question for the benefit of posterity (as my edit of his answer wasn't accepted).

### Micro level

The edited example works as intended, but some confusion remains.

- If I uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then nothing changes.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta`, then the compilation crashes.
- If I write `{\aa}tta` instead of `åtta` **and** uncomment `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then the compilation again does not finish.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@@unitstringgerman[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    null%
    \or ein%
    \or zwei%
    \or drei%
    \or vier%
    \or f\"unf%
    \or sechs%
    \or sieben%
    \or åtta% Changed from "acht" to "åtta"
    \or neun%
  \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\zz}{% Supposed to make the first letter of `\@@unitstringgerman{8}` (i.e. "åtta") uppercase
  \def\one{}%
  \def\two{}%
  \eappto\two{\@@unitstringgerman{8}}%
  % \edef\one{\noexpand\MakeUppercase\expandonce\two}%
  \edef\one{\MakeTitlecase{\two}}%
  \one%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \zz
\end{document}
```

### Macro level

The macro level example also works as intended and behaves the same as the micro example to the permutations.

```latex
\documentclass[german]{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\FCloadlang{german}
\makeatletter
% Redefine code from fc-german.def
\renewcommand*\@@unitstringgerman[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    null%
    \or ein%
    \or zwei%
    \or drei%
    \or vier%
    \or f\"unf%
    \or sechs%
    \or sieben%
    \or åtta% Changed from "acht" to "åtta"
    \or neun%
  \fi
}%
\global\let\@@unitstringgerman\@@unitstringgerman
\renewcommand*{\@NumberstringMgerman}[2]{%
  \@numberstringMgerman{#1}{\@@num@str}%
  \edef#2{\MakeTitlecase{\@@num@str}}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \newcounter{mycounter}
  \setcounter{mycounter}{8} \themycounter\ \Numberstring{mycounter}\\
\end{document}
```