# Cannot use \aa in \eappto with pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, etoolbox, fmtcount, diacritical-mark

I'm working on [a Swedish language file to `fmtcount`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674596/load-custom-language-for-fmtcount). There I have to concatenate strings to form numerals. As the Swedish words for two and eight ("två" and "åtta") contain the letter "å", I need to do things like in the minimal example below. And while this works just fine in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but fails with pdfLaTeX unless I include the `fontenc` package.

Do you have any suggestions for how I could do something like the example below with pdfLaTeX without including `fontenc`?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@unitstring}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    noll%
    \or ett%
    \or tv{\aa}%
    \or tre%
    \or fyra%
    \or fem%
    \or sex%
    \or sju%
    \or {\aa}tta%
    \or nio%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\zz}[1]{%
  \def\@tmp{}
  \eappto{\@tmp}{\@unitstring{#1}}
  \@tmp
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \zz{2}% works for 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 9 but not for 2 or 8
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm still not understanding what would be the reeason for `\eappto`. And what would be the real problem you're trying to exemplify with `\zz`.

Comment: you should always have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` anyway unless writing in English otherwise hyphenation will be wrong. Why are you avoiding it?

Comment: You could use `två` rather than `tv{\aa}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As I'm writing this as an addition to `fmtcount` I felt that I shouldn't load any further packages. But I guess that something like `\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi` wouldn't be all that intrusive. Then I could also write `å` instead of `\aa` :-)

Comment: @egreg I think that the reason why [`fc-german.def`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/blob/master/trunk/fc-german.def) (from `fmtcount`), which I based my code on, uses `\eappto` is that all of or part of the string later can be changed to uppercase. E.g. [`\edef#2{\noexpand\MakeUppercase\expandonce\@@num@str}`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/blob/master/trunk/fc-german.def#L124) where `\@@num@str` is the string or [`\protect\MakeUppercase{\@fc@numstr}`](https://github.com/vincentb1/fmtcount/blob/master/trunk/fmtcount.sty#L1623) where `\@fc@numstr` is the string.

Comment: @FredrikP it would be better to fix your code not to use edef which is not supported, but in practice it s OK to assume a recent latex, almost no one gets packages "by hand" from ctan and anyone getting your package by updating in miktex or texlive will have a current latex